# Как в Chrome убрать Flash, не пользуясь расширениями?

Tags: google-chrome

Как в Chrome убрать Flash, не пользуясь расширениями?

Comment: А зачем?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Перейти на страницу chrome://plugins, найти Flash и отключить.

Answer (score 2):

Если ты хочешь отключить Flash только на одной странице, зайди на сайт, в адресной строке нажми значок i и выбери: Плагины->Всегда блокировать на этом сайте. Также и с камерой, микрофоном, JavaScript и т.д.